# How to change Search Engine to DuckDuckGo in Maxthon?

Tags: macos, browser, browser-addons, maxthon

I'm using Maxthon (v5.1.130) web-browser on macOS and I'd like to change the default search engine to DuckDuckGo.com.

I've checked in Maxthon's Settings, but the *Search Engine* list is fixed and DuckDuckGo is not on the list.

How can I change it? Is there any workaround?

[image: Maxthon's Settings, Search Engine, On startup, Home Page, Google, Yahoo, Bing, Yandex, Amazon, Baidu]

[image: Maxthon's Settings, Search Engine, On startup, Home Page, macOS]

Comment: You have no add link? [Mouse Gesture - Help - Maxthon 3.0 Browser](http://www.maxthon.com/mx3/help/setup/search.htm) "You can **add**, edit, delete search engine, Change order of them, or set the keywords for each search engine if you like. "

Comment: I've included a screenshot of the settings page how it looks like. It's v5.1.130.

Comment: So what version are you running? And what is your OS?

Comment: I'm using the latest v5.1.130

Comment: I've just installed it. Settings > General > Default Search Engine > Search Engines Management

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UN7xpTG.png

Comment: Mine looks very limited, maybe because of macOS version. See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/euM3g.png